# how to convert nested object to querystring in node using http module

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, query-string

I need help to send a nested object on the POST request to stripe API using standard http module on node.js
When I use querystring module to convert the json to a querystring it does not give appropriate output.
It does not behave well with a nested object.

This is my payload object:

```
const payload = {
  "card": {
    "number": number,
    "exp_month": exp_month,
    "exp_year": exp_year,
    'cvc': cvc
  },
};
```

My helper method to send HTTP POST request:

```
helpers.createPaymentToken = (payload, callback) => {
  //validate the parameters
  if (payload) { //configure the request details
    const stringPayload =queryString.stringify(payload)
    //configure request details
    const requestDetails = {
      protocol: "https:",
      hostname: "api.stripe.com",
      method: "post",
      path:
        "/v1/tokens",
      auth:config.stripe.authToken,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload),
      },
    };
    //instantiate the request
    const req = https.request(requestDetails, function (res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      var body = '';
      console.log(res)
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body = body + chunk;
      });
  
      res.on('end',function(){
        console.log("Body :" + body);
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
          callback(res.statusCode,body);
        } else {
          callback(null);
        }
      });
  
    });
    //bind to an error event so it does not get thrown
    req.on("error", (e) => {
      callback(e);
    });

    //Add the payload
    req.write(stringPayload);

    //end the request
    req.end();
  } else {
    callback("Given parameters are missing on invalid");
  }
};
```

expected querystring:

```
card[number]=****************2&card[exp_month]=11&card[exp_year]=2021&card[cvc]=***
```

expected output:(request body)

```
{
  "card": {
    "number": "************4242",
    "exp_month": "11",
    "exp_year": "2021",
    "cvc": "***"
  }
}
```

actual output: (request body)

```
{
  "card": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently handling card details directly which you shouldn't attempt for security reasons.

Since you are collecting card details, you should use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) which is Stripe's UI library to collect card details client-side securely while meeting the lowest level of PCI compliance. You can read more about PCI compliance [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance).

Comment: Thanks actually i checked it out it is much easier with  Elements